# How to read jstl text from property file and display in jsp using jstl

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I need to pull html text from property file and display in jsp. Im able to read the plain html text but the html text has `<C:out>` s in the middle and the `c:out` text is displayed in the frontend instead of the out put value.       sample code below.

HTML text in the property file:

```
 An outage has been detected. Expected restoral time<c:out value="${var1}"/>
```

I created a tld file which picks the property from .properties file. Used the below format to pick the property

```
 <c:out value="${fnESUP:pick('propertyname')}"/>
```

Can someone please let me know how to pull the text along with the jstl tag and display in the jsp?

The text is diaplyed as it is in the page, instead of displaying the `<c:out>` value. Please someone help hpw to get the `cout` value while reading from properties file.

Comment: There are a couple of problems here. First, you can't have jstl in a property file -- the values in the property files aren't parsed, they're just passed through as strings. Next: c:out has been depricated for some time now and we simply use the template directly (${var1} for example). Finally, there is a standard way to do what you need to do, but this isn't it.

Comment: someone suggested we need to put string constants and then replace it. Can you please let me know how we can do that?

Comment: You should be using resource bundles, as per the JEE spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakw.html

Comment: if i use resource bundle, i have to place the props file in classes folder, instead i wanted to place it in server path. If i need to pick it from server path, using tld file(which uses java method in turn to read the property) is the only option i found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the jstl library in the JSP page?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: yes i have imported...When i put the text directly in the jsp, im getting the cout values, but whn im trying to pull it from properties file, its displaying cout  instead of the value .